# How to Serialize a MultipartFile to JSON for Testing in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently writing integration tests for a Spring application, and I've come across an issue while trying to test a POST request using a custom DTO that includes a field of type MultipartFile. The DTO represents a request payload for creating a field in a farm, and one of the fields is a boundary file of type MultipartFile.

Here's a simplified version of my DTO class:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CreateSomethingRequestDto {
    // Other fields...
    
    @Schema(description = "Boundary file for the something", name = "boundaryFile", required = true)
    private MultipartFile boundaryFile;
}
```

In my integration test, I'm trying to create a JSON representation of the DTO using the toJson method, but I'm facing an issue with serializing the MultipartFile field. Here's the relevant part of the test:

```
@Test
void create_somethingDoesNotExist_returnsWithStatusNotFound() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    CustomUserImpl customUser = new CustomUserImpl(savedAccount1);
    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile =
        new MockMultipartFile(
            "boundaryFile", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "filecontent".getBytes());

    CreateSomethingRequestDto createSomethingRequestDto =
        createSomethingRequest().setBoundaryFile(mockMultipartFile).setAnotherId(UUID.randomUUID());
    String json = toJson(createSomethingRequestDto);

    // WHEN
    mvc.perform(post("/somethings").with(user(customUser)).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

However, the test fails because the MultipartFile cannot be serialized to JSON using the toJson method.

How can I properly serialize the MultipartFile field in the DTO to JSON for testing purposes while keeping my current code structure intact? Is there an alternative approach or workaround that I can use in my unit tests?

Comment: Don't mix Multipart and JSON. Those are different types. You either send a multipart-type response, or a JSON-type response. Of course, you could send JSON as *one part of* a multipart response, but I don't think that's what you are asking.